# Writing Data to Text file for every five Minute Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, data-export

Suppose vec_A, vec_B, vec_c are some matrices with random data. I want to write data to text file for every 5 min, My code as follows:

```
function samplegui_OpeningFcn(hObject, ~, handles, varargin)

handles.timer = timer(...
       'ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate', ...   % Run timer repeatedly
       'Period', 300, ...                % Initial period.
       'TimerFcn', {@open,hObject}); % Specify callback

handles.output = hObject;
handles.vec_A=[];
handles.vec_B=[];
handles.vec_C=[];
guidata(hObject, handles);

function open_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles) % push button to receive serial data.

cnt=0;

while 1
       
       % Getting data  from Serial Port
        get_lines=fgets(handles.se) % getting data from serial port 
           if~isempty(get_lines)
            cnt=cnt+1;   
       if strfind(get_lines,'T')   %Parsing data
       handles.vec_A=[handles.vec_A;[timet newword]];
       plot(handles.vec_A(:,1),handles.vec_A(:,2:end),'r'); % plotting

       % Same follows for parsing and plot vec_B and Vec_C
       drawnow(); % to update the Plots
       end
     end
Pause(.05);
   
      start(handles.timer);  % saving the data
      dlmwrite('My_sample1.txt',handles.vec_A);
      dlmwrite('My_sample2.txt',handles.vec_B);
      dlmwrite('My_sample3.txt',handles.vec_C);
      stop(handles.timer);
end
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

While running my code, following error occurs:

> Error while evaluating TimerFcn for timer 'timer-6'
>
> Too many input arguments.

How to execute timer in this case to write data successfully for every five minutes or suggest any other way to do it.

Comment: And what is the question? Or what is the issue with your code?

Comment: @Lati please look at the edited post.

Answer (score 2):

You have defined your `TimerFcn` to be `{@open, hObject}` but you don't have a function named `open`. Instead, it is trying to call the built-in [`open`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/open.html) with three input arguments (the timer object, an event object, and `hObject`) and this is producing the error because `open` only accepts one input argument.

That being said, it's not clear at all how the code that you have provided will accomplish anything close to what you want. Something like this may work better.

```
function samplegui_OpeningFcn(hObject, ~, handles, varargin)

    handles.timer = timer(...
            'ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate', ...   % Run timer repeatedly
            'Period', 300, ...                % Initial period.
            'TimerFcn', @(s,e)write_data()); % Specify callback

    handles.output = hObject;
    handles.vec_A=[];
    handles.vec_B=[];
    handles.vec_C=[];
    guidata(hObject, handles);

    start(handles.timer);

    %// Now update your data in a loop

    cnt = 0;

    while true
        %// Getting data  from Serial Port
        get_lines = fgets(handles.se) 
        if ~isempty(LINES)
            cnt = cnt + 1;   
            if strfind(LINES, 'T')
                handles.vec_A = [handles.vec_A; [timet newword]];
                plot(handles.vec_A(:,1), handles.vec_A(:,2:end),'r');
                drawnow
            end
        end
    end

    function write_data()
        %// Write it to file
        dlmwrite('My_sample1.txt',handles.vec_A);
        dlmwrite('My_sample2.txt',handles.vec_B);
        dlmwrite('My_sample3.txt',handles.vec_C);
    end
end
```

Comment: This doesn't serve my purpose. The open function in my post is the push button to receive data real time from serial port to  collect, plot. and save data .

Comment: @MaK Of course it's not *exactly* what you need because 1) you haven't shown the relevant code and 2) this is a demonstration of *how* to do it using example data. You will have to adapt is slightly to your use case. For starters, if you have an `open` function, **show it to us** because that is where the issue is.

Comment: I briefly included the code, Please let me know, if you need any information still.

Comment: @MaK Did you actually read the first line of my post? You don't have an `open` function so that is causing your error.

Comment: @MaK I have updated the code to match what you have posted.